# post versus patch in editing vs. rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following [this rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) using rails 4.2.4.

The tutorial advised me to replace a form like:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

with:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

in a simple edit form. Note that I've been mapping as I go from 'article' to 'reading'.

The partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for :reading do |f| %>
```

My controller method is:

```
  def edit
    @reading = Reading.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Well, the result of this is a form that uses POST, while the routes (as per the tutorial) are only set up for PATCH. So, using the render for the partial, is there a way to instruct it to use PATCH? The tutorial claims that it will be inferred, but clearly that's not a happening thing.

```
No route matches [POST] "/readings/1/edit"

Rails.root: /Users/bensonmargulies/haftorah

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

Routes:

```
puck% bin/rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
  main_index GET    /main/index(.:format)        main#index
    readings GET    /readings(.:format)          readings#index
             POST   /readings(.:format)          readings#create
 new_reading GET    /readings/new(.:format)      readings#new
edit_reading GET    /readings/:id/edit(.:format) readings#edit
     reading GET    /readings/:id(.:format)      readings#show
             PATCH  /readings/:id(.:format)      readings#update
             PUT    /readings/:id(.:format)      readings#update
             DELETE /readings/:id(.:format)      readings#destroy
        root GET    /  

                      main#index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails knows to use `POST` versus `PATCH` when you pass an `ActiveRecord` model to the `form_for`. For records which are new, it will use `POST`; for records which already exist in the database, it will use `PATCH`.

In your case, you are passing a symbol to the form, not an actual record. Try changing it from `form_for :reading` to `form_for @reading`

Comment: I bet I missed that in the tutorial.